# How to write a regular expression that matches and indefinite number of groups?

Tags: regex

I have a configuration file where rules are defined in the format

```
RULENAME : STRING > STRING | STRING > STRING | ... (as many STRING > STRING as necessary)
```

Bellow is an example:

```
Rule1 : Type1.Output > Type2.Input;

Rule2 : Type1.Output > Type2.Input |
        Type3.Output > Type4.Input;


Rule3 : Type1.Output > Type2.Input |
        Type1.Output > Type2.Input |
        Type1.Output > Type2.Input |
        Type1.Output > Type2.Input;
```

Just to be clear ANY whitespace (or amount of spaces) is valid between the :, > and the |. The rule ends with the ;

The file will contain other information but none of it has this format. So I would like to write a regular expression that will match each of these rules. The match groups should return the rule name each rule (these are separated by the |) and, if possible (I don't know if it is), subgroups for each string on each side of the > for each rule.

So for Rule2 the match would look something like this:

```
Group 1: Rule2
Group 2.1 Type1.Output 
Group 2.2 Type2.Input
Group 3.1 Type3.Output
Group 3.2 Type4.Input
```

If the subgroups are not possible, I'm ok with a result .ike

```
Group 1: Rule2
Group 2: Type1.Output > Type2.Input
Group 3: Type3.Output > Type4.Input
```

In case it matters, I will be using this in QRegularExpressions in a Qt/C++ program

Comment: Why not just split the string on the `|` character?

Comment: You meant match (.*):(.*); and the split the string? I could, but I figured it was better to just use regular expressions. I would also need to determine how make sure that . matchets everything

Comment: QRegExp regexps has no support of `\G` assertion hence you will have to use a loop to capture all the matches.

Comment: QRegularExpression, supposedly expanded QRegExp in be more "pearl-like" which is why I'm using it. How would the regular expression be written with that assertion?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO, as you know, is not a code on request service

Comment: Also, what I believe you're asking for is not a job that is not great for regex alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCRE (and most regex implementations') repeated capture groups do not capture all matching groups, only the last match. For example:

```
"abcd" s|(\w)*|\1|
```

returns

```
d
```

not

```
a
b
c
d
```

Thus you cannot have a regex match **and** return all matching capture groups when you repeat capture groups.

You can take a code based approach using regex as one of your tools though, using a regex to capture the entirety of a Rule, then splitting that rule string on `|` and trimming whitespace from the returned substrings.

Comment: Sorry, about the late reply. Thank you. This is exactly what I did: https://regex101.com/r/nSY693/1

Comment: nice, dont forget to upvote/accept answers which you find helpful/solve your question ;D